# How does the pentaho shell step works and how does pentaho logs the shell step output

Tags: shell, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I am trying to read the code of the Pentaho DI. Especially, I am very much interested in understanding the logging and wait mechanism of the pentaho DI jobs until the shell step completes. Can anyone help me with the details. I could not get the required info on the shell step.

https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job will wait for the shell step to complete. Logging is done by the OS, so this will follow the normal logging of the OS.

[Documentation for the shell step](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Shell)

The Java code for the execution of the script is [here](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/blob/master/engine/src/org/pentaho/di/job/entries/shell/JobEntryShell.java#L578).

Comment: do you have any code snippet how pentaho redirects the logging after making the java call.

Comment: When you use a Shell job entry, Pentaho Data Integration makes a Java call to execute a program in a specified location. The return status is provided by the operating system call. For example, in batch scripting a return value of 1 indicates that the script was successful; a return value of 0 (zero) indicates that it was unsuccessful. You can pass command line arguments and set up logging for the Shell job entry.

Comment: i would like to simulate the same in java. I could get the java call to run a shell script but the java program executes the remaining steps without waiting for the shell script to complete the process.